# Batch: rename file summing a specific number to a string

Tags: batch-file, rename

I need to create a batch file that rename all the files in a directory summing +250 to a specific number positioned in a specific position of the string.

I'll try to explain better with an EXAMPLE.

**INPUT FILES**:

- 1410141603209_f06t**003**v0003600000F.dat.gz
- 1410141603508_f06t**005**v0003600000F.dat.gz
- 1410141603508_f06t**006**v0003600000F.dat.gz
- 1410141603508_f06t**010**v0003600000F.dat.gz

**OUTPUT FILES**:

- 1410141603209_f06t**253**v0003600000F.dat.gz
- 1410141603508_f06t**255**v0003600000F.dat.gz
- 1410141603508_f06t**256**v0003600000F.dat.gz
- 1410141603508_f06t**260**v0003600000F.dat.gz

As you can see, the only part of the string that I need to change is the bold part, summing +250.
Just another one information... the highest number that the input file can reach is 010, so the highest number that the output file can reach is 260.

Thanks in advance everybody for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
rem main cycle
for %%i in (*.gz) do call :rename_to_increased_number %%i
rem finish and go home
goto end


rem "function" rename_to_increased_number - receive one filename and rename it 
:rename_to_increased_number

SET FN=%~1
rem FN - is full file name

SET NUMBER=%FN:~18,3%
rem NUMBER - is a part of filename from 18 to 21 symbols

rem correct 009 => 9, 021 => 21:
IF %NUMBER:~0,1%;==0; SET NUMBER=%NUMBER:~1%
IF %NUMBER:~0,1%;==0; SET NUMBER=%NUMBER:~1%

rem receive addition
SET /A BIGNUMBER = %NUMBER% + 250

rem rename old filename to part_before_18,new_number,part_after_21
ren %FN% %FN:~0,18%%BIGNUMBER%%FN:~21%

rem exit "function" rename_to_increased_number
exit /b

:end
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer.
I tried to use it on this example:
1410141738545_f06t009v0003600000F.dat.gz
the output file renamed is
1410141738545_f06tv0003600000F.dat.gz

It cuts off the number 009 in this case, do you know why?

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: I list here below the issues that I see:
1) the files with the name 009 delete the number from the string
2) the files with the number 008 became 257 (not 258)
3) the files with the number 010 became 258 (not 260)
Al the other files (with 001,002,003,004,005,006,007) are ok and the .bat file works properly!

Comment: I did not realize than 009 and like one the Batch interpretates as number in other Numeral system.. I will edit my answer now.

Comment: Thanks it's perfect now!!
I would like to give you one up vote but I can't!!
THANK YOU
Now, I can and I do!! =)

Comment: @MarcaSolkanar - There is a potential nasty bug with this code. Because the file is renamed, the simple FOR loop may reprocess an already renamed file. Switching to a FOR /F with the DIR command eliminates the possibility of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the 3 digit number is always between t and v, and neither t nor v appears earlier in the name, then all you need is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=tTvV" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d ?????????????_???t0??v??????????F.dat.gz'
) do (
  set /a "num=1%%B+250-1000"
  ren "%%At%%Bv%%C" "%%At!num!v%%C"
)
```

The above also assumes the last character of the base name is always F. If that is not true, then you could substitute another ? for the F, but then it may match names that are too short. You could pipe the result to FINDSTR to make the file mask more precise.

Since you know that the largest input number is 010, I hardcoded the first digit as 0 in the file mask. This makes it safe to run the script multiple times on the same folder without fear of repeatedly adding 250 to the number.

Comment: Edit - Bug fix: added the required DIR /B option.